# AWS Lambda boto3 : Instance launch from lambda boto3 python eroor

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

while trying launch instance from python function instance not launching but not getting python syntax error.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    images = ec2.images.filter(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'description',
                'Values': [
                    'lambdaami',
                ]
            },
        ],
        Owners=[
            'self'
        ])

    amis = sorted(images, key=lambda x: x['CreationDate'], reverse=True)
    print amis[0]['ImageId']
    INSTANCE = ec2.create_instance(ImageId='ImageId', InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
    print(INSTANCE[0].id)
```

Kindly help.....

Comment: What error, specifically do you see?  Did you `import boto3`?

Comment: Yes ```import boto3```   Error on lambda ```errorType": "AttributeError",
  "errorMessage": "'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'create_instance```

Comment: Then you've not posted a complete code example. Any answer will likely be a guess.

Comment: I have updated please check.

Comment: Try just running EC2 instance from Boto3, after getting a connection, proceed with next steps.

Comment: EC2 launched when I using ami-id but goal is I want to launch instance from latest ami. I think I am doing mistake on calling ```ImageId``` 
when I try to run each singe command lambda showing ```null``` value so my code is right but not perfect. Kindly help for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined ec2 twice,

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')
```

and even again for client. Please use only one `client` or `resource`. Furthermore, there is no `create_instance` and it seems a typo of a function `create_instances` for resource.

---

Here is an example:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    images = ec2.images.filter(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'description',
                'Values': [
                    'lambdaami',
                ]
            },
        ],
        Owners=[
            'self'
        ])

    AMI = sorted(images, key=lambda x: x.creation_date, reverse=True)
    IMAGEID = AMI[0].image_id

    INSTANCE = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=IMAGEID, InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
    print(INSTANCE[0].image_id)
```

---

To make an image from an instance and wait for that,

```
import boto3
import time

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    instanceId = 'What instance id you want to create an image'

    response = ec2.Instance(instanceId).create_image(Name='Image Name')
    imageId = response.image_id

    while(ec2.Image(imageId).state != 'available'):
        time.sleep(5) # Wait for 5 seconds for each try.

    # Since we know the imageId, no needs for other codes

    instance = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=imageId, InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
    print(instance[0].image_id)
```

Comment: ```import boto3
import json
region = 'us-east-2'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     response = ec2.describe_images(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'description',
            'Values': [
                'lambdaami',
            ]
        },
    ],
    Owners=[
        'self'
    ]
)
     amis = sorted(response['Images'], key=lambda x: x['CreationDate'], reverse=True)
     print amis[0]['ImageId']
     INSTANCE = ec2.create_instance(ImageId='ImageId', InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
     print (INSTANCE[0].id)```

Comment: ^^ Output 
```Response:
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      21,
      "lambda_handler",
      "print amis[0]['ImageId']"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "IndexError",
  "errorMessage": "list index out of range```

Comment: Please do not include your code as a comment but just modify your answer. And I modified my answer several times, please check it again.

Comment: Btw, what is the `'ImageId'`? You didn't defined.

Comment: is ```ImageId``` can directly fetch from describe images. ? I thought.! ..

Comment: You obtain AMI list and I think you want to select an image from AMI. If you correctly set `ImageId` then the error will disappear I think.

Comment: Could you please guide me for that. actually I am not good in python. I just made this code for automise ec2 lauch using lambda.

Comment: `'ImageId' ` should be an id of Image but what you set is not. What do you want to select an image? That is up to you.

Comment: That's it! You want the first AMI image right? So, I added code to select the first AMI's ID.

Comment: One more error, ```Response:
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      20,
      "lambda_handler",
      "IMAGEID = AMI[0].image_id"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "IndexError",
  "errorMessage": "list index out of range"
}```

Comment: That means that there are no images with your filter condition.

Comment: When all things going good then again.. ```Response:
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      22,
      "lambda_handler",
      "INSTANCE = ec2.create_instance(ImageId=IMAGEID, InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "errorMessage": "'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'create_instance'"
}```

Comment: Now its working for me now. ```INSTANCE = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=IMAGEID, InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)```
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you help me more . My goal is launch instance from latest ami. 
So should I create new one and lauched from it. but the issue is If I create ami with same code then ami creation will take time to complete, Can you please add more code to wait until ami complete and then use that AMI to create new instance. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think that the kind of synchronous job is not good for lambda. But if you want, then you can add some code.